# Sutta on the two kinds of (debt) giver, people of guṇā?

Tags: reference-request, sutras, teachers

Thinking about the two kinds of goodness in giving, and about debt when we receive a gift ([*guṇā*](https://suttacentral.net/define/gu%E1%B9%87a)), my person just thought to ask if there is a Sutta which points the different kinds of debt to those two kinds of giving?

One kind of (debt) giver is perhaps best embodied by Mara: e.g. [enemies disguised as friends](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.nara.html), or the strings of sensuality (*kāmaguṇā*). The other kind of (debt) giver (who gives debts torward debtlessness: end of *upādāna*, entertainment) is the *Bhagavatā*, the One who can Give, the Liberal, along with the other gods (starting by parents, teacher, admirable friends).

Just thought, next to the many Suttas around this fact, if there might be one direct pointing out the two kinds of *guṇā* and the debts in receiving the given, the inclination to certain destination by association and increasing debts.

Of course given, free of the first kind of *guṇā* (without wordily strings), Dhamma given in line with Dhamma, is preferred, is possible acceptable.

(For those possible not so familar with the use of the word *guṇā*, it's used as "goodness" in dhammic countries, for example "person of goodness"/"figue of merits" when speaking about people who one by dhammic law owes debts, like parents, leader, teacher... While the word is also used for the givers of sensuality.)

*[Note: This question is a gift of Dhamma, not meant for commercial purpose or other kinds of low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange]*

Comment: Johann. Please provide an explanation of or a link to the "two kinds of goodness in giving". Thanks

Comment: That's the request Dhammadhatu. It's not good to answer the own question is it usually sad.

Answer (score 1):

The two kinds of debt can be found in the [Ina Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an06/an06.045.than.html).

The first kind of debt is that of money and material possessions:

> "Monks, for one who partakes of sensuality, poverty is suffering in
> the world."
>
> "Yes, lord."
>
> "And a poor, destitute, penniless person gets into debt. For one who
> partakes of sensuality, getting into debt is suffering in the world."
>
> "Yes, lord."
>
> "And a poor, destitute, penniless person, having gotten into debt,
> owes interest payments. For one who partakes of sensuality, interest
> payment is suffering in the world."
>
> "Yes, lord." ........
>
> "Thus, monks, poverty is suffering in the world for one who partakes
> of sensuality. Getting into debt is suffering in the world for one who
> partakes of sensuality. Interest payment is suffering in the world for
> one who partakes of sensuality. Being served notice is suffering in
> the world for one who partakes of sensuality. Being hounded is
> suffering in the world for one who partakes of sensuality. Bondage is
> suffering in the world for one who partakes of sensuality.

The second kind of debt is that of virtue (*sila*) and good conduct:

> "In the same way, monks, whoever has no conviction with regard to
> skillful mental qualities, no sense of conscience with regard to
> skillful mental qualities, no sense of concern with regard to skillful
> mental qualities, no persistence with regard to skillful mental
> qualities, no discernment with regard to skillful mental qualities is,
> in the discipline of a noble one, said to be **poor, destitute, &
> penniless.**
>
> "He — poor, destitute, & penniless, having no conviction with regard
> to skillful mental qualities, no sense of conscience... no sense of
> concern... no persistence... no discernment with regard to skillful
> mental qualities — engages in misconduct by way of the body,
> misconduct by way of speech, misconduct by way of the mind. For him, I
> tell you, **this is getting into debt**.
>
> "For the purpose of concealing his bodily misconduct, he formulates
> evil desires: He desires, 'May they not know about me.' He resolves,
> 'May they not know about me.' He speaks, [thinking,] 'May they not
> know about me.' He makes an effort with his body, [thinking,] 'May
> they not know about me.' For the purpose of concealing his verbal
> misconduct... For the purpose of concealing his mental misconduct, he
> formulates evil desires: He desires, 'May they not know about me.' He
> resolves, 'May they not know about me.' He speaks, [thinking,] 'May
> they not know about me.' He makes an effort with his body, [thinking,]
> 'May they not know about me.' For him, I tell you, **this is interest
> payment.**

The two kinds of gifts to help alleviate the two kinds of debt can be found in [Iti 100](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/iti/iti.4.100-112.than.html#iti-100):

> "There are these two kinds of gifts: a gift of material things & a
> gift of the Dhamma. Of the two, this is supreme: a gift of the Dhamma.
>
> "There are these two kinds of sharing: sharing of material things &
> sharing of the Dhamma. Of the two, this is supreme: sharing of the
> Dhamma.
>
> "There are these two kinds of assistance: assistance with material
> things & assistance with the Dhamma. Of the two, this is supreme: help
> with the Dhamma.
>
> "There are these two kinds of mass-donations: a mass-donation of
> material things & a mass-donation of the Dhamma. Of the two, this is
> supreme: a mass-donation of the Dhamma."